# How to Split Single Column to two Columns in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have small question about SQL Server, please tell me how to solve this issue.

[image]

I have table with Single Column Name "Name", I Need to Split that into Two Column AgentName and Agent Value as shown below

Comment: The patindex function will help you with this.

Comment: Is there always 3 rows after "agent1" value in `Name` column?

Comment: Why you are storing data like this. Sort out that first

Comment: these data are coming from Dyamic Grid of Webpage in JSON Format and hence its not possible to sort out.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana There may be 3 or 6 Under Agent1 or Agent2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following

```
Select IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS ident,
       case IsNumeric(Agent)
        when 1 then Agent 
        else null end ValueField,
       case IsNumeric(Agent)
        when 0 then Agent
        else null end AgentId
 from yourAgentTable
```

but don't expect the results to be like how you are asking

you will get answer which is like

```
----------------------------------------------------
Ident           |     ValueField       | Agent
----------------------------------------------------
1                   null                 Agent1
2                      1                 null
3                      2                 null
4                      3                 null
5                   null                 Agent2
6                      4                 null
7                      5                 null
8                      6                 null
```

hopefully now you should have the identity in which you are getting the data and how in its order as well,

now do a update statement to get the AgentIds where its null and you will have your data.

Comment: `IsNumeric` is not **reliable** to identify non-numeric data

Comment: that is the data given VR46 so thought could help. its again implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution. Variable @tbl has test data, variable @result_tbl will have output. I hope, this helps.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @result_tbl TABLE(agent_name NVARCHAR(100), VALUE NVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @agent_name NVARCHAR(100)

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'Agent1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Agent2'
UNION ALL
SELECT '4'
UNION ALL
SELECT '5'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Agent3'
UNION ALL
SELECT '6'

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM @tbl AS T
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @value

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @value LIKE 'Agent%'
    BEGIN
        SET @agent_name = @value
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @value
    END

    INSERT INTO @result_tbl
    VALUES(@agent_name, @value)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @value
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT * FROM @result_tbl
```